# Storyboard xib gets "stuck" after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've been programming with iOS since the beginning and had never used storyboards until just now. I have the situation now where sometimes after I change something in the storyboard the entry/first view controller gets "stuck". Its viewDidLoad method is called, but viewWillAppear is never called.

Undoing the change typically doesn't fix the issue. Instead doing random things such as deleting an outlet and then re-adding will then sometimes get the view controller to load properly. It has gotten really annoying as sometimes it takes 15-20 minutes of random changes and reverts. I have not found anything relevant in online searches.

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1.
There are no layout issues displayed within Interface Builder and no messages to the console log.

EDIT:
I was able to find a small change in Interface Builder that when in place causes the loading to get stuck and when removed, it works fine. This is repeatable. Here are the two diffs of the relevant sections in the storyboard. The first is making a leading constraint apply to all size classes and not just compact width. This creates the second change, an update to the view's size and position. These are the only diffs

`</label>
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wGJ-ag-Esv" userLabel="Label">
-                                <rect key="frame" x="33" y="20" width="266" height="25"/>
+                                <rect key="frame" x="41" y="20" width="258" height="25"/>
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Calibri-Light" family="Calibri" pointSize="17"/>
<color key="textColor" red="0.7843137255" green="0.7843137255" blue="0.7843137255" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
<nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>`

`-                            <constraint firstItem="wGJ-ag-Esv" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="faX-t4-9PC" secondAttribute="trailing" id="OTw-xP-VtH">
-                                <variation key="widthClass=compact" constant="4"/>
-                            </constraint>
+                            <constraint firstItem="wGJ-ag-Esv" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="faX-t4-9PC" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="4" id="OTw-xP-VtH"/>`

Comment: I absolutely agree that I am waving my hands. The difficulty is that it is a heisenbug inside a rather large project. My brief testing did not replicate any issues with a simplistic example. I do not have a UITextView, but that is exactly the sort of information and potential gotchas I'm hoping to discover.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. The view outlet for the entry view controller was accidentally set to a subview. I have no idea why it usually worked and randomly changing things would fix the problem, but I believe that was the problem.